# Compare and order objects in an arraylist, java

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` composed of `Student` objects. These objects contain first name, last name, lab grade, project grade, exam grade, and total grade. I am trying to write a function that sorts the `Student` objects in the `ArrayList` based on their total grade.

Here's my Student class:

```
public class Student {

// fields
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private int labgrade;
private int projectgrade;
private int examgrade;
private int totalgrade;

// constructor
public Student(String firstname, String lastname, int labgrade,
        int projectgrade, int examgrade) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.labgrade = labgrade;
    this.examgrade = examgrade;
    this.totalgrade = labgrade + projectgrade + examgrade;
}

// method
public String toString() {
    String s = firstname + " " + lastname + " has a total grade of " 
            + totalgrade;
    return s;
}
public int compareTo(Student s) {
    return (totalgrade = s.totalgrade);
}
```

And here's what I tried to do to sort:

```
private ArrayList<Student> arraylist = new ArrayList<Student>();
public void SortStudent() {
    Collections.sort(arraylist);
}
```

But that doesn't work because it says it can only work on `List` not `ArrayList`. Any help to fix my `SortStudent` method?

Comment: An `ArrayList`is a `List`.

Comment: Your `compareTo()` is wrong. `totalgrade = s.totalgrade` is an *assignment*, not a comparison. To compare, use `return Integer.compare(this.totalgrade, s.totalgrade)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArrayList` is a `List`, the problem is that `Student` does not implement `Comparable`, and you didn't define the `compareTo` method, which you need to do to use the `sort` method from `Collections`.
You could do something similar to this:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    //... the rest of the class
    public int compareTo(Student s) {
        return Integer.compare(this.grade, s.grade);
    }
}
```

Another option would be to use lambda expressions with the method `Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T> c)`, where you don't need to implement `Comparable`:

```
public void sortStudent() {
    Collections.sort(arraylist, (s1, s2) -> Integer.compare(s1.grade, s2.grade));
}
```

Comment: `implements Comparable` -> `implements Comparable<Student>`

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.sort` only works for types that implement Comparable:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {...}
```

---

Implementing `Comparable<...>` with `Student` is a bad choice in this case, since the sorting criteria are likely to change. e.g. sometimes you want to sort by first name, and sometimes by last name.

`List<...>` has a sort method that takes a `Comparator`, you could use that:

```
private ArrayList<Student> arraylist = new ArrayList<Student>();
...
public void SortStudent() {
    arraylist.sort((x, y) -> Integer.compare(x.totalgrade, y.totalgrade));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  class Student implements Comparable{  
          int rollno;  
          String name;  
          int grade;  
    Student(int rollno,String name,int grade){  
       this.rollno=rollno;  
       this.name=name;  
       this.grade=grade;
    }  

    public int compareTo(Object obj){  
      Student st=(Student)obj;  
      if(grade==st.grade)  
      return 0;  
      else if(grade>st.grade)  
      return 1;  
       else  
    return -1;  
    }
```

Comment: Okay I'm impressed you can implement a `compareTo`, but how does this help? You've offered no explanation.

Comment: with comparable, you specify how your object are to be compered